# Flutter app on IOS - push notification background color is black?

Tags: ios, flutter, icons, push

Has anybody experienced this or knows how to fix it?

iOS app built in Flutter using Firebase messaging. Using xcode 12 to publish.
My firebase notifications come through fine, and in Xcode I have set up the iPhone Notifcation and iPad Notification icons to an image with a transparent background. But when I receive a notification, the background color is black :S

[image: Note the black background color. How do I make this transparent?]

Comment: Does your icon is a format png with transparent background?

Comment: @ArbiterChil yes. And the same icon is looking correct on Android

Comment: on ios required an icon with a color background if its transparent it will give you black so thats why select an icon which have background white or something. I do also encounter this i just deliberately put my icon a white background jpeg or jpg

Comment: @ArbiterChil oh really? I didn't know Apple were preventing transparent backgrounds for push notification! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: even in asset when trying to choose icon for the app they wont accept transparent background on icons also in appstore

Comment: But in assets I provided a transparent background for iphone notifications and ipad notifications and it didn't tell me there was an issue.

Comment: in Xcode asset they wont tell but when uploading in appstore sure they will tell

Comment: They didn't when I uploaded (archived) for test flight. Maybe they would once submitted for approval. Thanks again. Man, apple sucks